# Exponential of a Quartic

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I know there is a related post regarding this, but does anyone know a 'closed' form solution for the integral
\begin{equation}I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\,e^{ax-bx^{4}}\end{equation}
I know you can do a series expansion of the quartic term, but I'd like to find a way that avoids that. The integral should converge as $e^{-bx^{4}}$ dominates at large $x$ and so the integrand quickly goes to zero (for $b>0$ obviously). Any help/ references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maple has this...in terms of hypergeometric ${}_0F_2$ functions:
$$
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-b{x}^{4}+ax}}{dx} =
\frac{\displaystyle  
2\,\sqrt {2}\pi \,
{\mbox{$_0$F$_2$}\left(\ ;\,1/2,3/4;\,{\frac {1}{256}}\,{\frac {{a}^{4}}{b}}\right)}
\sqrt {b}+  \Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right)   ^{2}{a}^{2}
{\mbox{$_0$F$_2$}\left(\ ;\,5/4,3/2;\,{\frac {1}{256}}\,{\frac {{a}^{4}}{b}}\right)}
 }{4 {b}^{3/4}  \Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right)  }
$$

Comment: I wish that Maple had some kind of trace derivation thing for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can't work backwards and figure this one out.

Answer (score 3):

Integrating by parts leads to $$I=\left.x\cdot e^{ax-bx^4}\right\vert_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(a-4bx^3)e^{ax-bx^4}\,dx=-a\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}-4b\frac{\partial I}{\partial b},$$but $\,\partial I/\partial b=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^4e^{ax-bx^4}\,dx\;$ also equals $-\partial^4I/\partial a^4$, so $I(a)+aI'(a)=(aI(a))'=4bI^{(4)}(a)$, or $\;aI(a)=C+4bI'''(a)$. Since $I(a)$ is even (and entire, of course), $I'(0)$ and $I'''(0)=0$ and so $C=0$; and using the integral formula for the gamma function, $$I(0)=2\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^4}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-y}b^{-1/4}\frac{dy}{4y^{3/4}}=2^{-1}b^{-1/4}\Gamma(1/4)$$ and $$I''(0)=2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-bx^4}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty b^{-1/2}y^{1/2}e^{-y}\frac{b^{-1/4}dy}{4y^{3/4}}=2^{-1}b^{-3/4}\Gamma(3/4)$$I plugged all of this into [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%3D4ay'''%7Cy'(0),+y'''(0)%3D0,+y(0)%3Da%5E(-1%2F4)*1%2F2*gamma(1%2F4),y''(0)%3Da%5E(-3%2F4)*1%2F2*gamma(3%2F4)) and got the same result as @GEdgar (with $x,a$ replacing, respectively, $a,b$).

Answer (score -7):

This is called Gaussian, it is not integrable by elementary means. First you need to make the substitution $a \rightarrow ax$ so that the integral is easier. Now the integral is $$\int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{ax^{2} -b x^{4}} dx$$
Now this is an easier integral if you make the substitution $x \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ because the integral is now 
$$\int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{ax^ - b x^{2}} dx$$
Ok, now we are really on track, because you can complete the square. Rewrite the integral as 
$$\int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{-b(x-\frac{a}{2b})^{2}}e^{-(ax)^2} dx$$
Now we are almost done, just pull out the last factor to get 
$$e^{-(ax)^2} \int _{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{-b(x-\frac{a}{2b})^{2}} dx = e^{-(ax)^2} \sqrt{\pi}$$ 
Now we have to evaluate somewhere because this is a function of x whereas the original integral is not. I picked 0, but any other value should work. So, the answer is $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: That factorization doesn't work because $x$ is not a free variable. If it were $e^{-(ac)^{2}}$ it could be taken outside the integral sign.

Comment: This is just plain wrong.  $x=\sqrt{y} \implies dx = dy/(2 \sqrt{y})$.

Comment: Yeah he forgot that you need to change the dx's also

Comment: Not to mention substituting $ax$ for $a$.

Comment: Wait a minute: "First you need to make the substitution $a \mapsto a x$..."  Do you know anything about calculus and integration?  Please do not pose as an expert on something about which you know very little.

Comment: Peter might have the right *idea* though. I think you can reduce the integrand to something like 1/sqrt(y)*e^[-(y-a)^2].

Comment: @AdamRubinson: how?  He ended up posing very different problem than the one the OP posed.  The integral from the OP is hard, period.

Comment: Of course you are right. I missed the ax and read ax^2

Comment: Here is another way; take partial with respect to a and b and use Feynman integration rule.

Comment: @PeterHalburt: I don't mean to be bad-mannered, but please, just stop.  There is no such thing as a "Feynman Integration Rule" that is relevant here; Feynman did not invent differentiating under the integral sign.  And, even if he did, differentiating under the integral sign is useless here.

Comment: Feynman does talk about his rule in his book "surely you are joking mister feynman" and he talks about how he could solve ANY integral using this method, so i think you are judging too early :o)

Comment: @PeterHalburt: you know, Sheldon in the Big Bang Theory discusses various algebraic manipulations, but you sure as hell are not going to see me describe the quadratic formula as The Sheldon Cooper Quadratic Equation Rule.

Comment: In any case, the whole point is moot.  As I said, differentiation under the integral does not help here.  Go ahead and prove me wrong.

Comment: Oh ok maybe there is simplier way. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx=2\infty$ Then times $e^{ax-ax^{4}}$. Very Simple.